# check if condition exists in object

Tags: vue.js

In a Vue JS app I'm working on the following structure is being passed into a component as a prop to create nav links:

```
const data = [
                {
                    category: 'Part 1',
                    items: [
                        {
                            'title': 'plan A',
                            'etlJobRefresh': false,
                            'type': 'form'
                        },
                        {
                            'title': 'plan B',
                            'etlJobRefresh': true,
                            'type': 'form'
                        },
                        {
                            'title': 'plan C',
                            'type': 'form'
                        },
                        {
                            'title': 'plan D',
                            'type': 'query'
                        },

                    ]
                },
                {
                    category: 'Part 2',
                    items: [
                        {
                            'title': 'plan A',
                            'type': 'form'
                        },
                        {
                            'title': 'plan B',
                            'type': 'query'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    category: 'Part 3',
                    items: [
                        {
                            'title': 'plan A',
                            'etlJobRefresh': false,
                            'type': 'form'
                        }
                    ]
                }
];
```

The component contains an element that is to be displayed only if the `data` prop contains items that have `'eltJobRefresh': true && 'type': 'form'` .  How do I check the incoming data prop to see if that condition exists without using a third party library?

Comment: Created a computed property that tests the condition using nested [`some`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) then use `v-if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use computed property for filtering

```js
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: `
  <div>
    <div v-for="element in computedData">{{element.title}}</div>
  </div>
  `,
  props: ['data'],
  computed: {
    computedData: function() {
      let list = [];
      this.data.items.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element.eltJobRefresh);
        if (element.etlJobRefresh && element.type == 'form') {
          list.push(element);
        }
      });
      return list;
    }
  }
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    data: [{
        category: 'Part 1',
        items: [{
            'title': 'plan A',
            'etlJobRefresh': false,
            'type': 'form'
          },
          {
            'title': 'plan B',
            'etlJobRefresh': true,
            'type': 'form'
          },
          {
            'title': 'plan C',
            'type': 'form'
          },
          {
            'title': 'plan D',
            'type': 'query'
          },

        ]
      },
      {
        category: 'Part 2',
        items: [{
            'title': 'plan A',
            'type': 'form'
          },
          {
            'title': 'plan B',
            'type': 'query'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        category: 'Part 3',
        items: [{
          'title': 'plan A',
          'etlJobRefresh': false,
          'type': 'form'
        }]
      }
    ],
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <my-component :data="data[0]"></my-component>
    <my-component :data="data[1]"></my-component>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```